# What is the proper way of calling a function with an array as arguments within a contract?

Tags: solidity

Say I have a function like this:

`function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts`

and I want to call it within another solidity function

```
function callBatchMint() external {

    <CONTRACT>.mintBatch(.....);
}
```

what would be the proper way to pass in an array of arguments? I have tried in the past and gotten `TypeError: Type address payable[3] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] memory`

Answer (score 1):

Error suggests that you are passing arguments of `address payable` type but your function expects just `address` type arguments. So either ammend your function to accept `address payable` type arguments or don't pass `address payable` as arguments, **instead** pass `address` type arguments